# If the characters avoid the encounter through diplomacy, are they awarded the XP for the monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, experience-points, encounters, social-combat

Let's say that a part of the dungeon with X monsters can be either passed through combat OR through careful diplomacy, can the players be awarded XP points the same way if they choose the latter? It seems like it's a cool way to reward role playing instead of just fighting - and the players can save spell slots/per-rest abilities at the cost of the loot. Is that something that D&D supports?

Comment: Related: [How should XP be awarded for an encounter when enemies flee, get intimidated, or are convinced to help?](/questions/133483), [Are there alternative ways to gain XP?](/questions/53527), [How do I deal with players who make friends with goblins?](/questions/134590)

Comment: Not an answer to this particular question but as a DM you can award XP however you like, or play without any XP at all (which I'm personally more used to).